# Multi-Dimensional ArrayList initialized with values

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm new to coding.  My teacher recently introduced arrays and arraylists.  I have a multi-dimensional array like this:

```
private String[][] pods = {{"pod1", ""}, {"pod2", ""}, {"pod3", ""}, {"pod4", ""}};
```

I'd like to switch this to an arraylist, as I need to edit the information in there.

***How would I do this, but with a multi-dimensional ArrayList?  I'd like to initialize it with the above information.***

I've tried this:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> pods = new ArrayList();
```

Whenever I put stuff between the parenthesis, I get an invalid operator error.

By the way, just in case anyone was wondering - this is NOT a class assignment. This is something I'm trying on my own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your approach is half-correct.

You can have an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s for a double-dimensional array.

However...

You're initializing your `List` as a raw type. From Java 7, you can just change your assignment to a diamond-type for inference:

```
List<List<String>> pods = new ArrayList<>();
```

In earlier versions:

```
List<List<String>> pods = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

You also need to populate your lists.

For that, you'll need some iteration.

Here's a complete Java 7 example (using `List` as "code to an interface" guideline suggests).

```
String[][] info = {{"pod1", ""}, {"pod2", ""}, {"pod3", ""}, {"pod4", ""}};
List<List<String>> pods = new ArrayList<>();
for (String[] level1: info) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(level1);
    // use this instead if you intend to modify the inner lists
    // List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(level1));
    pods.add(list);
}
System.out.println(pods);
```

**Output**

```
[[pod1, ], [pod2, ], [pod3, ], [pod4, ]]
```

And now, some Java 8 mojo:

```
String[][] info = {{"pod1", ""}, {"pod2", ""}, {"pod3", ""}, {"pod4", ""}};
List<List<String>> pods = 
    Arrays.stream(info)
        .map((a) -> Arrays.asList(a))
        // use this instead if you intend to modify the inner lists
        // .map((a) -> Arrays.stream(a).collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(pods);
```

**(same) output**

```
[[pod1, ], [pod2, ], [pod3, ], [pod4, ]]
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList` returns a fixed size `List`. I believe you wouldn't be able to append elements to the inner `List` with this solution.

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis that is true, although not a requirement to the original question. The easiest solution would be to wrap the invocation in the constructor I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely want a one liner like when you use arrays you can use this "one liner" (you will also need `import static java.util.Arrays.asList;`):

```
List<List<String>> pods = new ArrayList<>(asList(
    new ArrayList<>(asList("pod1", "")),
    new ArrayList<>(asList("pod2", "")),
    new ArrayList<>(asList("pod3", "")),
    new ArrayList<>(asList("pod4", ""))
));
```

Comment: I don't think you need all the new ArrayList<> bits -- you could just do it with the asList() bits. Besides, you shouldn't be referencing ArrayList at all in your code, most of the time.

Comment: Unfortunately `asList` returns a fixed size `ArrayList`. If you need to append elements after initialization, you need to use the copy constructor for a "proper" resizeable list. Otherwise yes it would simplify things a lot.

Comment: and the OP does actually mention the need to edit the data in the lists, so fair enough

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding items to your `pods` ArrayList by creating the inner ArrayLists first, and then using `pods.add`:

```
// create your initial ArrayList
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> pods = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

// create an ArrayList<String> to add to it
private ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("foo");

// create another
private ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
list2.add("bar");

// add the inner ArrayLists to your main ArrayList
pods.add(list1);
pods.add(list2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate on array and add items to a list. 
When you are finished with a row, just add list to main list.

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for ( int i = 0 ; i < rowsCount ; i++ )
{
   List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
   for ( int j = 0 ; j < colsCount ; j++ )
    temp.add ( arr[i][j]);
   list.add (temp);

}
```

or you can do as following :

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < rowsCount ; i++ )
{
   list.add (Arrays.asList(arr[i]));
}
```

> But using second approach will prevent you from expanding each list item at any index

Comment: Code alone is considered a low quality answer. You should point out why this answers the OP's question